# Trim last characters of word in full text search

Tags: php, search, full-text-search

I have autocomplete options saved in my DB. My search is giving results in exact way as it is written which is the way i need it. Full text.
But when it comes to searching I want to trim last 2 characters from each searched word. Even if the search query is made up of multiple words.

The problem is with my native language which uses different last 1-2 characters in adjectives depending on the gender of the noun. Deal is that the user wont have to type different kind of adjectives to get different results but so that he gets all the same results no matter which way he types in the adjective. Will this be possible?

Example

What you type in : 1. bonita chicita   2. nice girlie

Fulltext searched: 1. boni chici      2. ni girl

Comment: Can you post some examples with expected outcome?

Comment: Posted additional examples. Its basiclly a full text search with last characters trimmed...lets say 2 char in each word.(1 word only in the example)

Comment: You keep confusing me. You say trim 2 char in each word but you only trimmed the last word in your examples? Otherwise a simple substring would do?

Comment: Sorry that was just an example...wanted to keep it in easy language..of course all the words will be trimmed :)

Comment: A substring would do if you say all the words will be trimmed off the last 2 characters of every word. Please post as an answer so i can send it to my colleague to point him in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: So for your 2 examples the expected outcome should actually be `boni chici` and `ni girl`?? Or are those examples correct and only the last word (chicita and girlie) get trimmed?

Comment: All the words are trimmed. But the problem is in the database it is saved as NICE GIRLIE. which means do we have to trim it in the database too ?

Comment: Surely you'd want the `NI GIRL` saved in the database to match any version given? As you said there are many ways of typing the last 2 characters so why only save `NICE GIRLIE` in database?

Comment: Well I imagine it this way. NICE GIRLIE stored in DB. Then u type NICE GIRLIE in the input. But the search goes searching for NI GIRL.and still finds NICE GIRLIE as a result

Comment: Check my answer now, is this something you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I will answer how to trim the last 2 characters off each word supplied and will update the answer as/when new information comes through.

```
$string = 'bonita chicita';
$array = explode(' ', $string); // Adds each word into an array

// Loop through each word in the array and remove the last 2 characters
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $array[$i] = substr($array[$i], 0, strlen($array[$i])-2) . '%'; // For adding wildcards in place of the 2 removed characters
}

// Recreate the string from the array
$newString = implode(' ', $array);

// This will now echo boni chici
echo $newString;
```

You could also put this into a function for multiple uses.

```
function editString($string) {
    $array = explode(' ', $string); 

    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
        $array[$i] = substr($array[$i], 0, strlen($array[$i])-2) . '%'; // For adding wildcards in place of the 2 removed characters
    }

    return implode(' ', $array);    
}

echo editString("bonita chicita"); // echos boni chici
```

For searching purposes with the way your database is designed you need to put % wildcards in place of the removed 2 characters so maybe add in `$array[$i] .= '%'` after the `substr()` then use the newly wildcarded string to search the database.

I attempted this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1cf0/6) and it seemed to work.

Comment: I was told we are using "match against". We must continue using full text search. We cannot change that. Will this work in full text search ?